# Swipe.js - Simple Detection of User's Scrolling Direction (Back or Forward?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This is simple, I'm sure of it, yet too complicated for me at the moment.

Swipe.js, a mobile slider, provides lots of good information on each slide, as well as a two functions that can be performed during a slide and at the end, yet I'm having a hard time writing some simple logic that detects whether the user is scrolling to the next slide, or previous:

**Swipe.js:**  https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

**Available functions:**

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

**Swipe's Simple API**

```
Swipe API
Swipe exposes a few functions that can be useful for script control of your slider.

prev() slide to prev

next() slide to next

getPos() returns current slide index position

getNumSlides() returns the total amount of slides

slide(index, duration) slide to set index position (duration: speed of transition in milliseconds)
```

Comment: Try to see what is sent to your callback function. See what index is, and what elem is. And see what you could do with these two arguments.

Comment: You could set a variable outside the object to keep track of the index, then within the `callback` or `tranisitionEnd` compare that value to the current index given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could get you there. You'll want to only do this in one of the callback functions in production but I'm not sure which exactly gives the index of slide you just transitioned to, so I put in both for you.

```
var sliderIndex = 0;
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  callback: function(index, elem) {
      if (index < sliderIndex) {
         //backwards 
      }else{
         //forwards
      }
      sliderIndex = index;
  },
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {
      if (index < sliderIndex) {
         //backwards 
      }else{
         //forwards
      }
      sliderIndex = index;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check API docs for slideNextTransitionStart, slideNextTransitionEnd, slidePrevTransitionStart, slidePrevTransitionEnd